# How can I align my checkbox with css?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, checkbox

I need to do a form with checkboxes and a list. I used Bootstrap for my checkbox and list, but the problem is that the text and the checkbox are unaligned.

[image]

```
<div id="ContForm">
    <div id="Cajamitad1">
      <div class="checkbox">
        <label>
        <input type="checkbox" value="">Soy Vegano
        </label> 
      </div>

      <div class="checkbox">
        <label>
        <input type="checkbox" value="">Soy diabetico
        </label> 
      </div>    
    </div>

    <div id="Cajamitad2">
    <select class="form-control">
            <option>1</option>
            <option>2</option>
    </select>
    </div>

</div>
```

How can I align them?

Comment: try putting them both, the label and the checkbox in the class 'form-control'.

Comment: Your code looks fine here: http://www.bootply.com/pzubYV8xfi, are you using any custom CSS?

Comment: Please include your CSS in the question, otherwise we won't be able to answer it.

Comment: You must have other CSS interfering with the Bootstrap classes as everything looks good [in this JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/z87sqjpp/).

Answer (score 1):

You can use the classes provided by [`bootstrap.css`](http://getbootstrap.com/css/) like `form-control` or you can try this:

```
input {
  vertical-align: middle;
  line-height: 1;
}
```

This CSS ruleset says,*"Every input element will be vertically aligned to the middle, and has the equivalent height of an uppercase letter."*

```css
input {
  vertical-align: middle;
  line-height: 1;
}
```

```html
<div id="ContForm">
  <div id="Cajamitad1">
    <div class="checkbox">
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox" value="">Soy Vegano
      </label>
    </div>

    <div class="checkbox">
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox" value="">Soy Diabetico
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="Cajamitad2">
    <select>
      <option>1</option>
      <option>2</option>
    </select>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: However i am still wondering why there are so many divs nested in eachother.

Comment: I see that a lot with Bootstrap markup, doesn't say much semantically. Which by the way is more or less a guideline and not a way of life as some would have others believe. I don't like using a ton of divs, but I try not to push the subject with people new to code, they'll find out how clunky code can get later on like I did.

Comment: True, im just glad it isnt just a table, even though it can be extremely convenient for long forms sometimes. Clever use with sections etc. can be of great help too.

Comment: I like fieldsets even though Firefox does not.

Comment: firefox has more than just one bug tbh. Just read a post about this 3 seconds ago.