# Mozilla Firefox form input fields and buttons not lining up

Tags: css, symfony, less, twig, styling

## Form Fields not lining up in Firefox

Solved this one myself but it took a little while... Thought I would share it    out, also it would be nice to know if there is a more elegant cross-platform solution.

---

The problem was very similar, if not the same to this question: [How can I align my checkbox with CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36049521/how-can-i-align-my-checkbox-with-css).  The difference that I see is that in Chrome the fields lined up just fine.  While in Firefox they looked like the example in the link.

**This is the the code background:**

- Symfony 2 form builder
- Bootstrap with Custom Less/CSS Styling
- Twig/Html rendering

I originally thought that flexbox styling might offer a solution, because that has helped me resolve alignment issues in the past, after working through several different examples I found that this did not help at all and went to a simpler if possibly less elegant solution.

It is difficult to recreate a working example of the problem, don't know how or if it is possible to set up that specific a background in codepen, but this is the chunk of code from the .html.twig file:

```
 {{ form_start(form) }}
    {{ form_errors(form) }}
    {{ form_row(form.id) }}
    {{ form_row(form.embedded) }}
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12"><label id="subformHeader">Field(s)</label></div>
    </div>
    <ul id="sortable" class="fields subform" data-prototype="{{ form_widget(form.fields.vars.prototype)|e }}">
        {% for key, field in form.fields %}
                <li>
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-sort"></span>
                    {{ form_row(field.name) }}{{ form_row(field.type) }}{{ form_row(field.options) }}
                </li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
    <div class="btn-toolbar">
        <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-primary pull-left" />
        {% if id %}
        <a class="btn btn-warning pull-left" id="delete" href="?delete=y&id={{id}}">Delete</a>
        <a href="{{path('path_to_data')}}" class="btn btn-warning pull-left" id="reset">Reset</a>
        {% endif %}
    </div>
{{ form_end(form) }}
```

And this is the CSS/Less:

```
.subform {
 list-style: none;
 li {
    div {
        display: inline-block;

        label {
            display: none;
        }
     }
     .deleteLink, .fieldOptions {
        margin-left: 4px;
     }
 }
 li:first-child div label {
    display: inline;
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### This was the solution I came up with...

```
.subform {
 list-style: none;
 li {
    div {
        display: inline-block;

        label {
            display: none;
        }
        .form-group {
        box-sizing: border-box;
        vertical-align: bottom;
        }
     }
     span {
         vertical-align: 150%;
     }
     a {
        vertical-align: 110%;
     }
     span.glyphicon-option-horizontal,span.glyphicon-minus {
        vertical-align: -7%;
     }
     .deleteLink, .fieldOptions {
        margin-left: 4px;
     }
 }
 li:first-child div label {
    display: inline;
 }
}
```

Which aligned everything with a bit of tinkering:

[image: Fields Aligned]

Comment: You can accept your own answer, this will mark this question as resolved: http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer